# C# - Input a list of numbers with a certain range

Tags: c#

How do I get an input of 13 numbers and to make sure they're all between 0 and 9? I've been trying to find a solution for the past hour.

Comment: What do you mean by "Enter" ? Do you mean like at the Console prompt, or what ?

Comment: That was my bad, I asked the question in a strange way

Comment: What framework are you using, winforms, wpf...... ?

Comment: @Dyde what is the problem? the input? the checking? both? what have you tried?

Comment: guys, if he does not know how check number between 0 and 9, how he can know what is wpf, winforms, console prompt.

Comment: @Taumantis It determines how he is getting his input, without the information this question is unanswerable with making a flat out guess

Comment: @Taumantis, and how are WE supposed to know what he's trying to achieve without proper questioning ?

Comment: I'm new to stack, I asked some questions before when I've had issues. I'm new to coding with C#, this is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: @Dyde first do you create Console Application? Black 
rectangle with white letters?

Comment: @Dyde I understand that and we want to help, but you haven't given us all of the information, is this a console application ? how are  you wanting to get your numbers input implies external,  what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

inside a for-loop , use System.Random to get an int in the range 0 to 9.

hope that helps, I'm not coding the solution because...  well, if you are going to learn c# probably you better be able to do that yourself!

#### EDIT:

I'll go ahead and post my "answer" with the caviet:   If you are asking this for some professional reason (such as answering a school test question or passing an employment interview screening)  ***Then FYI: copy/pasting a solution someone else wrote on StackOverflow is going to cripple your ability to get (or keep) jobs in the future, and will reduce your ability to make money. ***  I would continue further elaboration, but I'm sure we all know the repercussions if we think it through a bit.

```
        var random = new Random();
        var list = new List<int>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        {
            list.Add(random.Next(10));
        }
```

Comment: I am new to to C# but I know enough. However I hate working with loops :3

Comment: If you hate working with loops you're probably in the wrong job! Seriously though, learn this stuff, it's important.

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq:

```
var AllAreBetween0And9 = listOfEnteredIntegers.All(x => x >= 0 && x <= 9);
```

Comment: if we are creative now, why not to use regexes?  `var AllAreBetween0And9 = listOfEnteredIntegers.All(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.ToString(), @"\b\d\b"))`

Comment: because Regex isn't DotNet enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

I do not belive that I am asnwering this but here you have:

**Adding**

```
 int[] inputs = new int[13]; // here you have inputs
            for(int i=0;i<13;i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please gimme number "+ (i+1));
                int value;
                value = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                inputs[i] = value;
            }
```

**Checking:**

```
 int[] ints = new[] {0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
        foreach (var i in ints)
        {
            if (i>=0 | i<9)
            {
                //i is between 0-9
            }
            else
            {
                //do nothing
            }
        }
```

p.s foreach is overdo, you can use `for` or other less functional loops, maybe It will force you to read something about this kind of issues

As you are afraind of loops... input without loops where `i{number}` can be `i[index]` of `int [] i`

**Adding without loop**

```
int i1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int i2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int i3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int i4 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int i5 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int i6 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int i7 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int i8 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int i9 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int i10 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int i11 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int i12 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int i13 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

**Checking with Regex**

```
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b\d\b");
```